# Split and print n th column in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a file which contains lines in below format.

```
{'This.is', 'string_1/test/testing_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}
{'This.is', 'string/test/splitting_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}
{'This.is', 'string_1/test/testing_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}
{'This.is', 'string/test/splitting_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}
```

I need to split these lines and print only the test-type which is `splitting`, `testing` as you can see in input file(Ex. From first line i need only `testing` as a output) also i want to print test-type of which string length equal to 7 or 8 (don't want to print `splitting` test-type).

In the above I need to get the output of

```
testing
testing
```

Already tried something like below which is not provide the result what I expected.

```
f = File.open("/root/tempfile.txt", "r")
f.each do |ln|
  ln.chomp
  fr = []
  fn = []
  fr = ln.split("/")
  puts fr[2]
end
f.close
```

Comment: Why not : 1. Open the file (File.open(...).each do |l| ) 2. Replace the opening and closing '{' and '}' by '[' and ']' 3. eval the string 4. do what you want ?

Comment: @Pholochtairze I got somewhat but still am not clear about your suggestion.

Comment: Well, I think you can get what you want with [`(?<=\b|_)\p{L}{7,}(?=\b|_)`](https://regex101.com/r/pM3sR2/1). Check http://ideone.com/iD81ju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input File :

```
{'This.is', 'string/test/splitting_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}
{'This.is', 'string/test/working_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}
{'This.is', 'string/test/nothing_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}
{'This.is', 'string/test/doing_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}
{'This.is', 'string_1/test/testing_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}
```

Code :

```
File.open("test.txt", "r").each do |l| 
  l.chomp
  fr = l.split("/")    
  str = fr[2].split("_").first
  str_len = str.length
  puts str if str_len == 7 || str_len == 8
end
```

Out Put :

```
working
nothing
testing
```

Comment: it worked! Thanks! But am getting the list where I have all the strings, I want to print only strings which contains 4 or 7 characters.

Comment: which string , could you specify in you question ?

Comment: That code produced below output

`splitting
testing
adopt
worked
try
`

But I want to print only the string character count is equal to 4 or 7

Comment: i have update my answer for checking string size , see updated one and if it is fulfill you goal accept and upvote the answer

Comment: Great! But am getting output as simply dots (.)

`"."
"."
"."
"."
"."
"."
"."
"."
"."
"."`

Comment: sorry to say still am getting simply dotted output only instead of getting respective strings

Comment: this is what i understood from your question posted above, can't help any more (update the question for what inputs and outputs you want).

Comment: My input:

`{'This.is', 'string/test/splitting_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}  
{'This.is', 'string/test/working_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}  
{'This.is', 'string/test/nothing_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}  
{'This.is', 'string/test/doing_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}  
{'This.is', 'string_1/test/testing_for/work', '/learn/word_in'}`

Expected Output:

`splitting
working
nothing
testing`

So I want the output which contain sting count is equal to 7 or 8 only on that particular column.

Comment: than why you have added splitting in your Expected output, string count of splitting is 9, i have updated answer for sting count is equal to 7 or 8

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your help! Sorry for that I confused